# I'm working with R. I am performing a k-NN analysis on the training data, but I keep getting an error on my knn function. How can I fix this

Tags: r

Here's my input:

```
For (j in I: m ){
      model.knn <- knn(train.set[,vars],
                             test.set[,vars],
                             cl = class.train,
                             k=j,
                             prob = T)
       error <- table(model.knn, class.test)

       knn.error[j] <- (error[1,2] + 
                              error [2,1]/sum(error))
}
```

Output:

```
Error in [.data.frame'(train.set, , vars) : undefined columns selected
```

Comment: The apostrophes are accents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error you are getting, it seems that you are trying to subset data frame `train.set` by selecting columns which do not exist in that data frame.  To rectify this, try the following code:

```
> colnames(train.set)    # lists all column names in train.set
> vars                   # prints all columns you are trying to select
```

You need to make certain that `train.set` has the columns which `vars` is trying to reference.  And while you are at it, you should do a similar check for the `test.set` data frame.